# Can I do anything about Facebook returning an error about 'Page Public Content Access' after a password reset?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've come on to help a company out at the last minute after a developer bailed, and I'm left with some annoying quirks. I'm also very green when it comes to Facebook API. I don't have all the history, but here are the facts as I know them:

I've got a Facebook application that is used by a single Facebook account. This Facebook application reads public content of various pages (pages of clients, to be more specific) on Facebook (specifically follower and like counts). Periodically on a web server, we get these numbers and update our records for said clients.

Now, this application has executed fine for months. For security reasons, we changed the password for the Facebook account associated with this Facebook app. After recreating the access token, I started getting the following error:

To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

My question is, why now? Why did a password reset cause this? Was this app originally grandfathered into not needing to be approved, and now that a password has been reset the app needs to be reviewed? In looking at the app's permissions it does seem it wasn't approved for this feature.

The reason I'm asking is if there's some other reason why this restriction was suddenly added, I'd like to know. Perhaps it's only applicable for certain scenarios and by updating the access token I inadvertently requested some feature the previous app never did?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to access public pages you do not own without getting "Page Public Content Access" approved now, this was changed a while ago already. So you are probably right, it may have worked only because of the old Token.

There are two ways to solve this:

- Get Page Public Content Access approved by Facebook
- Use a Page Token for all the Pages - you can only get it by having a role in the Page

Comment: I don't have the credentials yet to give you a public +1. But just to let you know, this was the response I was looking for. Thanks.